# Overriding NSDocument's fileWrapperOfType causes "Document could not be saved."

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, nsdocument, nsfilewrapper

I've got to be missing something simple, but Google is not helping.

My file saves and loads fine. (I've overridden `dataOfType` to get some stuff in it.) Then I override `fileWrapperOfType` (in preparation for creating a bundle), and I get a "The document 'Untitled' could not be saved as 'test'." sheet when I try to save. Even when I empty out my method to the absolute most basic form I can think of...

```
- (NSFileWrapper*)fileWrapperOfType:(NSString*)typeName error:(NSError**)outError
{
  NSFileWrapper* worldWrapper = [[NSFileWrapper alloc] initDirectoryWithFileWrappers:nil];
  return [worldWrapper autorelease];
}
```

...I still can't save. What am I missing?

Comment: As a general practice checking return values and - if available - `NSError` out parameters is always useful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the docs (emphasis mine):

> The dictionary *must* contain entries whose values are the file wrappers that are to become children and whose keys are filenames.

You use `nil` so my guess is that `worldWrapper` is `nil`, and returning `nil` is interpreted as not being able to save your file.

Comment: Close; I had checked to be sure that worldWrapper was non-nil (and it was). But this answer did prompt me to try using an empty dictionary rather than a nil one, and that worked. This still seems very unusual, though; don't most methods allow a nil dictionary in place of an empty one?

Comment: @andyvn22: Some methods do, some don't. It's becoming increasingly common that you need to pass an empty value of the desired type (dictionary, string, array, etc.) rather than nil, so it's generally a good idea to do that even if you're not sure it's necessary.